# How to split a feature collection in several equal parts in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, features, chart, feature-collection

I have a feature collection (fc) consisting of 44 polygons. I need to create a time-series chart of NDVI values for each of them. I would like to analyse these polygons in groups of 4 - 5. Grouping method does not matter; only separation is important.

Is there a code or function that takes fc as an input and subdivides it in vars of my desired size? In this case, the output would be 11 new feature collections, each with a group of polygons from fc.

Since I only need this for charting, a possibility that allows this separation to happen only in the charts would be even better. In this case, the output would be 11 time-series charts of NDVI values. If this is a possibility, it is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either statistically with `randomColumn()` and filtering, or since there are so few, just using a list and `shuffle()` and get an exact number of items per fold.

Here's an over-engineered function to split a collection into k pieces using `randomColumn`.  Note that not all the pieces will be exactly the same size because of randomness, so it works better with larger collections.

```
/**
 * Split a table into k parts.
 * Args: 
 *   table: the table to split
 *   k: the number of splits.
 * Optional args:
 *   percent: percentage to include in each fold.  default: 1/k
 *   replacement: Sampling with replacement?  default: false
 *   seed: random seed.
 */
function kfoldsRandom(table, k, percent, replacement, seed) {
  percent = percent || ee.Number(1).divide(k)
  replacement = replacement || false
  seed = seed || 0xbeef
  
  var folds = ee.List.sequence(0, k - 1).map(function(n) {
    // For replacement, reshuffle by making a new seed for each fold.
    var offset = ee.Algorithms.If(replacement, n, 0)
    var replSeed = ee.Number(seed).add(offset)
    
    var t = table.randomColumn('random', replSeed)
    var slice = ee.Filter.and(
      ee.Filter.gte('random', ee.Number(percent).multiply(n)),
      ee.Filter.lt('random', ee.Number(percent).multiply(ee.Number(n).add(1))))
    return t.filter(slice)
  })
  return folds
}
```

But when you have a small number of items, it's often just easier to turn it into a list and cut it into pieces.

```
  var step = table.size().divide(k).int()  // Or just set this to 4
  return ee.List.sequence(0, k - 1).map(function(n) {
    var start = step.multiply(n)
    return table.toList(100).shuffle().slice(start, start.add(step))
  })
```

If you want sampling with replacement, use `shuffle(n)` instead of shuffle.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/653d458b7acce6c70045125302672b53

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that I use. It works for `ee.FeatureCollection` and `ee.ImageCollection`, and all groups (except one) end up with the same size.

```js
function index_dict_batch(fc, batch_size, sortby){
    /*
    Returns a dictionary mapping a feature collection
    to a list of integers divided by batch_size
    */
    var indices = fc.sort(sortby).aggregate_array("system:index");
    var cellids = ee.List.sequence(1, indices.size());
    function assign_batch_id(element){
        return ee.Number(element).divide(batch_size).ceil();
    }
    var cellids_mod = cellids.map(assign_batch_id);
    return ee.Dictionary.fromLists(indices, cellids_mod);
}
function split_batch_collection(coll, batch_size, property, sortby){
    /*
    Assigns a property "batch_id" representing a batch number
    to each element in coll (ee.FeatureCollection | ee.ImageCollection)
    */
    var c_dict = index_dict_batch(coll, batch_size, sortby);
    function assign_batch_id(f){
        var bidx = c_dict.get(f.get("system:index"))
        return f.set(property,bidx)
    }
    return coll.map(assign_batch_id)
}
```

The result is the same FeatureCollection, but with an extra property that identifies the group in which each feature belongs, which you can use with a filter.

Here's a small demonstration that splits the administrative unit layers (FAO/GAUL/2015/level2) in California (N=58) into groups of 25 -- so you end up with two groups of 25, and one of 8:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/07523b56aebb54b11d84d67c87d6cb83